# How to set Text on Path on outside path in Sketch?

Tags: text, path, sketch-app

I would like to change put the text on the **outside** of circle and there is an issue, when the text is placed at the bottom at circle the texts are **squeezed** (Image 01) together, How to sovle this problem?

[image]

Comment: I'd advise you to make two separate questions: one for the flipping of the type to the outside of the path, one for the 'crowding' issue. That way, it's easier to get answers for both.

Answer (score 19):

Although it's not very intuitive, it is actually quite easy.

## TEXT ON THE OUTSIDE

After you've taken your "text on path", you select **only** the shape you used as a path and flip it horizontally.

## SQUEEZED TEXT

To "unsqueeze" the text, you can go either two ways:

1) Kern the letters until you're happy with the result or

2)Select the shape you used as a path and manipulate it (i.e. make it bigger and move it around) until the text is as desired.

Hope it helped. Any doubt, let me know.

Answer (score 14):

i wanted to add a new answer which doesn't create transforms and/or rotations on your text-path. (if you're exporting it to SVG).

If you want the text to be on the outside of the shape you should do the following:

select the shape > go to the top menu select **Layer** > **Path** and choose **Reverse Order**. This switches the **beginning point** with the **end point** and reverses the direction placing the text on the outside of the shape.

Follow [this link](https://medium.com/sketch-app/harnessing-vector-awesomeness-in-sketch-3c9621408138) for an awesome guide regarding this issue.

Hope it helped,

Comment: This is actually a better choice than flipping the path horizontally. With the **reverse order** you can still convert the text to outlines. With the flipped path you can't do that.